# Is it possible to have webpack-server trigger a page refresh on other file changes?

Tags: webpack

I have `webpack-server` configured to build my .js and .scss and it currently refreshes my page when I make changes.

Is it possible to have this happen when I change non-webpackable files such as html templates and php files?

I effectively want to watch a whole directory and tell webpack-server to reload when a file changes.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @ARS81 Nope, not yet

Comment: I made my situation working with webpack4 + browser-sync-webpack-plugin and so far it can handle everything I need. Devserver + HMR + browser reload on other watched folders. I can share my config as an answer if you interested.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there's no option (currently) for watching external files and do just a page reload on change, but there are workarounds:

**With Chokidar (easiest)**

I found it [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1271#issuecomment-359817498) and is working great for me. It needs [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) but webpack-dev-server [uses](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/package.json#L30) it also internally, so it should be already installed. If not, install it with npm or yarn.

So first require chokidar (maybe at the top of your webpack.config.js):

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
```

.. and the simplest way to achieve what you want is just a few lines added to the devServer config:

```
devServer: {
  before(app, server) {
    chokidar.watch([
      './resources/views/**/*.blade.php' // watch all my laravel view templates
    ]).on('all', function() {
      server.sockWrite(server.sockets, 'content-changed');
    })
  },
```

**With BrowserSync**

[BrowserSync](https://browsersync.io/) is a great tool for web developers with a lot of goods. There's a webpack [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin) which we need to install first with npm or yarn. It can operate well with webpack-dev-server together, but it creates an other proxy over devserver.

```
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
```

and then in your plugins config:

```
plugins: [
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
    proxy: "localhost:8080", // devserver
    files: [
      './resources/views/**/*.blade.php'
    ]
  },{
    // prevent BrowserSync from reloading the page
    // and let Webpack Dev Server take care of this
    reload: false
  })
```

Comment: That chokidar example - fantastic!!

Comment: Thank you!  Thank you!

Comment: I am having trouble getting this method to work with Webpack 5.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ARS81's answer, for webpack 5 the message and the method to send messages changed a bit:

```
devServer: {
  onBeforeSetupMiddleware(server) {
    chokidar.watch([
      '/some/files/to/watch/*.html',
    ]).on('all', function () {
      for (const ws of server.webSocketServer.clients) {
        ws.send('{"type": "static-changed"}')
      }
    })
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Having the same question as the OP I managed to get it working by simply using [the `watchFiles` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchfiles).

```js
devServer: {
  watchFiles: ["./some/files/to/watch/**/*.php"]
}
```

While the middleware way is still available it's not needed for the basic cases.